# How to add new element in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to add new element inside a React object, but I am getting below issue

```
const isAdmin = true
let schema = {
            fname: Yup.string().required('Required'),
            lname: Yup.string().required('Required'),
            ...(isAdmin && isFirstLogin) && {role: Yup.string()},
    };
```

It's working fine when isAdmin = true. But whenever I am doing isAdmin = false its showing me error like:

> Spread types may only be created from object types.

Why does it not work with false?

Comment: is isFirstLogin also a boolean?

Comment: @hellogoodnight truthy/falsey would still work there with `isFirstLogin`, but being prefixed with `is` I would expect it to a boolean type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

With `...(isAdmin && isFirstLogin) && {role: Yup.string()}` when `isAdmin` is false, then `(isAdmin && isFirstLogin)` evaluates to false. When this happens the rest of the boolean expression is ignored from the way javascript shortcuts out of evaluating the expression. It's at this point you are attempting to spread `false` into the `schema` but this fails since it isn't iterable.

## Solution

You need to handle the "unhappy" false path by still providing a value that can be spread. Using a ternary allows you to test the `isAdmin && isFirstLogin` condition and return `{ role: Yup.string() }` if true, and a spreadable empty object `{}` if false.

```
const isAdmin = true
let schema = {
  fname: Yup.string().required('Required'),
  lname: Yup.string().required('Required'),
  ...(isAdmin && isFirstLogin) ? { role: Yup.string() } : {},
};
```

```js
const isFirstLogin = true;

const schema1 = {
  fname: 'first',
  lname: 'last',
  ...(true && isFirstLogin) ? { role: 'role' } : {},
};

const schema2 = {
  fname: 'first',
  lname: 'last',
  ...(false && isFirstLogin) ? { role: 'role' } : {},
};

const schema3 = {
  fname: 'first',
  lname: 'last',
  ...(true && false) ? { role: 'role' } : {},
};

console.log(schema1, schema2, schema3);
```

Comment: This does not change anything. The problem is that he is trying to spread the boolean value false. It must be the case that "isFirstLogin" is a spreadable element, i.e. not a boolean.

Comment: @hellogoodnight Incorrect, everything in the `()` is evaluated before anything is possibly spread, i.e. `(isAdmin && isFirstLogin)` is evaluated before the rest of the line is. It's when `(isAdmin && isFirstLogin)` evaluated to `false` that `false` was attempted to be spread, and failed. This is why switching to a ternary and providing an empty object (`{}`) works and is spreadable. Check the stacksnippet I added.